# ImportError: No module named utilsload_data

Tags: python, django

My django has been working properly but suddenly if i try to run ./manage.py i get this error

```
ImportError: No module named utilsload_data
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Module `utilsload_data` is not on your python path, or the directory from which manage.py is being run.

Comment: so what can i do to fix it?

Comment: Where is the module located? Change your code to import it from the correct directory/package - or add the directory to your PYTHONPATH

Comment: am guessing it is in django and am in my virtualenv so i think it should be ok

Comment: I don't think that it is a standard django file. Where is it in your virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

Since a search for `utilsload_data` only brought up this question, I'm guessing that this is a typo in one of your files, any you are actually trying to `import utils.load_data` or some such.

Check the error stack to see where the failed import occurs and correct the typo. If you use git or some other version control system, you can easily go over the changes to the file to find out what the last working version was.